# Responsive bootstrap navbar menu items using css only without flexmenu js plugin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have implemented navbar using bootstrap.min.css. i am getting the bootstarp menus in two lines during tab resolution.

To resolve the above issue, i want the requirement like following image.

https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/375_responsive_menu/img/ipad.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the min height and width of menu.. according to tab..

like bootstrap provides us some css (sm -3,6, 9) class according to resolution , you have to do change in them or just create your new class as resolution you want.